# R - write.csv exported some value in a character field to NULL

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with accounting data. The Account field has values with all numbers, decimal numbers, and number and letters, e.g 66000, 6600.30, 6600M.

The Account field is imported as character.

When I exported the data frame using

```
 write.csv(df,"filename.csv",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
```

some of Account were exported as NULL, and some were exported to wrong decimal numers (e.g. 6600.299999999...)

df has over 8 millions of rows. When I exported a subset of df with the same line, the Account field was exported correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you can try to convert your Account field to character before exporting:

```
library(tidyverse)
write.csv(df %>% mutate(Account = as.character(Account), "filename.csv", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
```